# need help cloning in UEFI

Tags: uefi, lubuntu

I need help, I am trying to clone my UEFI Lubuntu 16.04 i tried so many tools but still wont boot. I tried clonezilla, minitool that copies everything but still wont boot.

After I cloned the usb disk i copied, on clonezilla give me a prompt "error invalid environment block" and when using minitool, i saw all partition was copied but still saying "no bootable device detected"

Is there any cloning application that i could just use?

Comment: Please edit your question and  give details about what you tried with clonezilla and the problems you encountered. I have extensive experience with the tool. But  no one can help with this sketchy description of the problems you encountered.

Comment: Sorry, already edited. Thank you.

Comment: I use Gnome-Disks running from a Live or Persistent Ubuntu USB. I use the `Create Disk Image` option not the `Create Partition Image` option. This clones the bootloader as well as everything else.

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.